# Adding a Sub Class to All Angular Models

Tags: javascript, angular, api, class, model

I am using AngularJS for web app and in that I am trying to read data from APIs. Thus i have made few Models in accordance with the API's result set. Among many Models, Lets talk about a single Model `TYPE`

```
//This is the JSON API is returning
{ 
   "records":[ 
      { 
         "ID":"1",
         "TYPE":"mythological"
      }
   ],
   "pagination":{ 
      "count":"1",
      "page":1,
      "limit":10,
      "totalpages":1
   }
}
```

Now I have made the following Model for `TYPE`

```
//type.ts
export class Type {
    "ID":string;
    "TYPE":string;  
}
```

After fetching the data from API i am successfully storing it and running through my code using following TYPE component ts.

```
//gallery.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { Type } from 'src/app/models/type';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss']
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  types: Type;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  clickfunction(){
    this.data.getData().subscribe(data=>{
        this.types=data.records;
        console.log(this.types);
    }); 
  } 
}
```

ALso, i am fetching data from this service

```
//data.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  dataUrl:string = 'http://localhost/api-slim/public/index.php/api/info/type';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl);
  }

}
```

Although the application is running its obviously giving me the following error, which i need to radicate.

```
Date: 2019-09-26T19:42:06.903Z - Hash: a1b41d5889df87ba0aa3
5 unchanged chunks

Time: 780ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

    ERROR in src/app/components/gallery/gallery.component.ts(23,21): error TS2339: Property 'records' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

**NOW**

The `pagination` data that the API is providing is common in each of the API response, but as you can see none of my models are consuming it. What would be the best way to store and use that `pagination` in each of my model. I have tried to made a temporary demo class  in `gallery.component.ts` as follows,

```
export class TEMP {
  records: TYPE[];
  pagination: [];
}
```

But it's ugly. Is there any efficient fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model class doesn't really reflect the API response.

A model is like a custom data structure that you can use like a data type like this:

```js
export TEMP { //consider renaming this to something more meaningful
   records: Array<Type>;
   pagination: Pagination;
}

export class Type {
   ID: string;
   TYPE: string;  
}

export Pagination{
   count: string;
   page: number;
   limit: number;
   totalpages: number;
}
```

Comment: So you're suggesting  that I should create a new Class `Pagination` and every time i am making an API call i should use this `TEMP` variable to handle my data?

Comment: I did this, `export class RawImportData<T> {
    records: Array<T>;
    pagination: {
      count: string;
      page: string;
      limit: string;
      totalpages: string;
    }
}
`
and declaring shits like `RawImportData<Type>`, Cool enough?

Comment: yeah, if you need to use generic type for your use case, I rarely use it though

Comment: Thanks, btw i see you're good at angular, i have some small queries of my own i would like to discuss with you. How can i reach you?

Comment: Hahaha thanks but I wouldn't say I am good. I am still learning everyday. I think it is better to post a new question if you have things you are not sure, this way, others who are more expert in angular will be able to participate and help you too

Comment: Hey @unkn0wn, if you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks!